# Logging requests and responses bodies in spring without requiring huge amount of ram

Tags: spring-boot

Customer wants to log **whole** request and response. IIUC standard spring way is to use org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter. But this revolves around usage  `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` resp. `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`. This works in default setting nicely, because:

```
new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request, getMaxPayloadLength());
//where:
DEFAULT_MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH = 50
```

but with

```
setMaxPayloadLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

we will endup with OOM, because of internal implementation:

```
public ContentCachingRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, int contentCacheLimit) {
    super(request);
    this.cachedContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream(contentCacheLimit);
    this.contentCacheLimit = contentCacheLimit;
}
```

I understand, that this is effort to optimize System.arrayCopy calls, but if I have thousands calls with reasonable bodies and say 1/hour which needs 5MB of ram, this implementation has significant memory requirement implications. And `ByteArrayOutputStream cachedContent` is used in some clever way storing more than just input/output stream, so I don't feel too comfortable to tinker with this implementation.

Is there any solution to that? I understand that logging everything is stupid idea, but if I have to do that, can I do that without huge memory block allocations?

**EDIT**: I do apologize, there is another constructor of class ContentCachingRequestWrapper:

```
public ContentCachingRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request)
```

so I could copy-paste `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` and call this one without cap specified. And I need to do the copypaste in all cases, since there is no support for response caching and no way how to plug that in. So this would setup cachedContent to content length **BUTTT** implementor forget, they also write query parameters  into `cachedContent` so if you have non-null body and some query parameters it wont work. If you have no body but query parameters bigger than 1024, it won't work. I think this constructor (and both classes) is (are) severely flawed.

Comment: No there isn't. As you can only read the inputstream from the request and response once. If you log it you already consumed it so you would need to cache the actual data.

Comment: I just realized you could use a [`TeeInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) to log the request when it gets read and a `TeeOutputStream` for the response. This wouldn't involve caching. I haven't tried it but in theory it should work. So ignore my first comment :). You would still need a filter that wraps the incoming request/response but instead of caching the writing would be transparent.

Comment: @M.Deinum you didn't understand me well in first comment: I do understand the need of caching with respect to possibility to read only once, BUT allocating theoretical maximum byte[] is exceptionally wasteful and does not scale at all. I'd expect allocate smaller array and resize it as needed. And I was wrong, please see the upcoming update, but it still does not solve the issue.

Comment: The query parameters are written only in case of a form post, if they wouldn't you wouldn't be able to retrieve both the form body and request parameters. It would then break one or the other, hence the need for caching that. It will also only cache if the inputstream hasn't been consumed. It isn't flawed it works in many implementations without issues.

Comment: I probably lack some knowledge then. If I have body-less post with query params, it's POST <url with query params>, then headers, then no-newline and no-body. I have no idea why this has to be cached, if it's not part of InputStream. But assuming it has to be, if I use new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request, 1) ie. 1 char ByteArrayOutputStream it will fail when writing parameters. — but I learned that 1024 max for bodyless posts is safety agreement while it's not required by rfc. So just using it without size limit should be fine.